# Unable to connect to SSH after generated public key and private key

Tags: ssh, cygwin, openssh

Can some one help ? I have installed openssh (version OpenSSH_6.8p1) in windows 7 and I have generated the public and private keys, however I'm not able to connect to that SSH. I'm getting an error "Connection closed by 127.0.0.1" if I use the command "ssh localhost" .

However I'm able to connect by skipping the public key authentication via "ssh localhost -o PubkeyAuthentication=no"

Output of the command "ssh -v localhost"

> OpenSSH_6.8p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2a 19 Mar 2015 
>  debug1: Reading
>   configuration data /etc/ssh_config
>  debug1: Connecting to localhost
>   [127.0.0.1] port 22.
>  debug1: Connection established.
>  debug1:
>   identity file /home/Vinoth/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
>  debug1:
>   key_load_public: No such file or directory
>  debug1: identity file
>   /home/Vinoth/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
>  debug1: key_load_public: No
>   such file or directory
>  debug1: identity file
>   /home/Vinoth/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
>  debug1: key_load_public: No such
>   file or directory
>  debug1: identity file
>   /home/Vinoth/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
>  debug1: key_load_public: No
>   such file or directory
>  debug1: identity file
>   /home/Vinoth/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
>  debug1: key_load_public: No
>   such file or directory
>  debug1: identity file
>   /home/Vinoth/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
>  debug1: key_load_public:
>   No such file or directory
>  debug1: identity file
>   /home/Vinoth/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
>  debug1: key_load_public: No
>   such file or directory
>  debug1: identity file
>   /home/Vinoth/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
>  debug1: Enabling
>   compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
>  debug1: Local version string
>   SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.8
>  debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote
>   software version OpenSSH_6.8
>  debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.8 pat
>   OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
>  debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
>  debug1: kex: server->client
>   aes128-ctr umac-64-etm@openssh.com none
>  debug1: kex:
>   client->server aes128-ctr umac-64-etm@openssh.com none
>  debug1:
>   expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
>  debug1: Server host key:
>   ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:4Lnpmdki8UuIiQtJyZoc2vxu8x9l
>   PVSN4vykW+axilc
>  debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the
>   ECDSA host key.
>  debug1: Found key in
>   /home/Vinoth/.ssh/known_hosts:1
>  debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
>   debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
>  debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
>   received
>  debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
>  debug1:
>   SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
>  debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT
>   received
>  debug1: Authentications that can continue:
>   publickey,password,keyboard-interacti ve
>  debug1: Next
>   authentication method: publickey
>  debug1: Offering RSA public key:
>   /home/Vinoth/.ssh/id_rsa
>  Connection closed by 127.0.0.1

List of files under .ssh folder

> $ ls -lrt
>   total 7
>   -rwxrwx--- 1 Vinoth None  519 Jun 11 18:36 known_hosts
>   -rw-rw---- 1 Vinoth None 1679 Jun 12 00:48 id_rsa
>   -rw-rw---- 1 Vinoth None  398 Jun 12 00:48 id_rsa.pub
>   -rw-rw---- 1 Vinoth None  398 Jun 12 23:47 authorized_keys

List of Files under /var/log

> $ ls -lrt 
>   total 54101
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 Vinoth Administrators    35167 Jun 11 15:10 setup.log
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 Vinoth Administrators    25541 Jun 11 15:10 setup.log.full
>   -rw----r-- 1 SYSTEM SYSTEM              469 Jun 11 15:43 sshd.log
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 sshd   Administrators 55330520 Jun 13 00:57 lastlog

sshd.log is not updating . lastlog file is not readable

cat sshd.log

> Vinoth@Vinoth-HP /var/log
>   $ cat /var/log/sshd.log
>   /var/empty must be owned by root and not group or world-writable.

Comment: well `$cat sshd.log` anyhow and see what it says

Comment: /var/empty must be owned by root and not group or world-writable.    This is the output of cat sshd.log

Comment: ok try the latest update to my answer

Answer (score 2):

The most likely explanation is that you have not set adequately restrictive file permissions on the keys in question. You may wish to set

```
  chmod 600 id_rsa
  chmod 600 id_rsa.pub
  cat id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys
  chmod 600 authorized_keys
```

which is strict enough.

Comment: still the same error, I have also added the list of files under.ssh folder

Comment: @Vinoth Did you change to 600 the  permissions of the directory *.ssh* too?

Comment: I don't know why .ssh folder is not showing when i do ls -lrt from the home path. But I have change the permission of .ssh to 770. it is visible from the windows explorer and also able to change the permission from the cmd.

Comment: @Vinoth .ssh cannot be seen because it is a hidden file. You can see by means of *ls -a*. 770 is certainly wrong, it should be 700. Try it.

Comment: still not working after I changed to 700 . Log file is same

Comment: @Vinoth please find error log for the server, not the client: they are in /var/log/ssh* and post them here.

Comment: @Vinoth `ls -ld ~/.ssh`  the -d makes sure it shows the attributes of the directory rather than the files within the directory.  700 for ~/.ssh  and 600 for the contents of ~/.ssh

Comment: @barlop this is the output 
$ ls -ld  ~/.ssh
drwx------+ 1 Vinoth None 0 Jun 12 23:59 /home/Vinoth/.ssh

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I have added the list of files under /var/log folder. I have noticed that sshd.log folder is not updating and the lastlog file is not redable

Answer (score 1):

you write

> I'm able to connect by skipping the public key authentication
>   via "ssh localhost -o PubkeyAuthentication=no"

Good

So `$ssh-copy-id localhost`

(then that should put the pub key from source, to the remote system ~/.ssh/authorized_keys)

exit

then

`ssh localhost`

and it should go straight in 'cos it'll try pub key first and it should work.

**added**

`ls -l  /var/log/sshd.log`

see when it was last written too, then  `cat /var/log/sshd.log`

or  I think `tail /var/log/sshd.log` to see the last/most recent entry there

**Added-b**

cat /var/log/sshd.log gave "/var/empty must be owned by root and not group or world-writable."

Try

$ chown root /var/empty
chown: invalid user: 'root'

You may get that error above. That may be a cygwin/cygwin openssh oddity.

So try

(maybe cygwin being absurd)

as mentioned here
https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2008-02/msg00429.html

try `$chown SYSTEM /var/empty`

And if it sitll doesn't work then cat sshd.log again you may get a new error there, which would be progress.

**added c**

you could try starting fresh
]you can try re-running ssh-host-config though i've found I had to even remove the sshd service (not just stop it), and delete keys in /etc  in order for ssh-host-config to really configure things fresh.

`sc stop sshd`  (or net stop sshd, or cygrunsrv -E sshd)

`sc delete sshd` (or cygrunsrv -R sshd)

`rm /etc/ssh*` (these are all files)

that may be enough but you could also do

`net user sshd /delete`

`net user cyg_server /delete`

remove any sshd or cyg_server user from /etc/passwd

And i've seen it suggested to remove /var/empty (though I didn't and my reinstall was fine)  https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2014-03/msg00315.html

You could reinstall cygwin (without uninstalling)  it just updates things e.g. when I did it I noticed one command got some more switches. All the things you had installed like openssh should still be ticked.

I don't think I had to reboot

Then open an administrative command prompt and run `ssh-host-config`   ok the defaults and net start sshd

Comment: $ ssh-copy-id localhost 
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter
out any that are already installed

/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: Connection closed by 127.0.0.1

Comment: @Vinoth see my update to my answer, and try that

Comment: I have added the output of cat sshd.log

Comment: @Vinoth I have had that one before, try latest update to my answer

Comment: Yes when I run chown root /var/empty i dot invalid user :'root' error and I tried $chown System /var/empty ,however stll not working and also sshd.log is not updating

Comment: @Vinoth try my latest update "added c"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24761/discussion-between-barlop-and-vinoth).